# Drupal 8 Custom Block how to attach JavaScript ?

Tags: drupal-8

I have created a custom block successfully and just want to call java script alert function on the block. I have created a .js file .The issue is how to call the function declared in the javascript throgh array render in build function of the BLOCK PHP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 7):

Please elaborate the question.
As per my understanding try this one.
[Reference](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)

Attaching js to a render array of a Block Plugin

To give another example of attaching a library to a render array, If you are building a block plugin in your module, you can attach the libraries to the render array in the build() function of your class extending the BlockBase class (as of Drupal 8 beta 6).

```
return [
  '#theme' => 'your_module_theme_id',
  '#someVariable' => $some_variable,
  '#attached' => array(
    'library' => array(
      'your_module/library_name',
    ),
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can attach a library to a Block in a twig file: 
1) supposing the block name is: **block--foobar.html.twig**
2) and you created a library in **THEME.libraries.yml** file called: **contact-js**
3) => you can attach the library to the Block by calling this in **block--foobar.html.twig** :
    **{{ attach_library('THEME/contact-js') }}**

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the js file first in `moduleName.libraries.yml`. Then you can run, the alert function will work.